# Android take photo without takePictureIntent

Tags: android, android-camera

I wrote this testing program to take photo in android

this is testing version, the final version is no activity, because the program will run in background

```
Camera camera;
Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {}
};
Camera.PictureCallback rawPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {}
};
Camera.PictureCallback jpegPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
        Log.v("takePhoto", "photo here");
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    camera=Camera.open();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallback, jpegPictureCallback);
        }
    });
}
```

and I got runtime error

```
Process: com.myapplication, PID: 14355
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
```

I also tried this

```
camera=Camera.open();
camera.startPreview();
```

but still got same error

how to make this program works?

Update:

this is complete error information

```
Process: com.myapplication, PID: 15122
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1290)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1235)
        at com.myapplication.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4453)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18464)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5064)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: there must be better error information than it `failed`

Comment: Have you given required permission for `Camera` to use in your `Androidmanifest` file?? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`

Comment: just missing `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`, added now, but same error

Comment: I found the solution, I need set a dummy SurfaceView to camera `SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
c.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
c.startPreview();` but it only works on some device, some device does not works, is there any better solution?